# Linux Shell Script - Diferença entre $(()) e (())

Tags: linux, shell-script

Estou estudando shell script e aprendi a usar $(()) e (()) pra fazer cálculos. Entendi a diferença: enquanto o $(()) serve pra fazer um cálculo e retornar o resultado do mesmo, o (()) serve pra criar/alterar uma variável, mas sem printar o resultado no shell atual. Exemplos:

```
echo $((10+10)) # imprimir 20
x=$((10+10))    # criar variável com valor 20
x=20; ((x++)); echo $x # imprimirá 21
```

Ou seja, me parece que os operadores $(()) e (()) são bem similares, com a diferença que o primeiro retorna o resultado do cálculo para o shell atual, enquanto o (()) apenas cria/altera uma variável, mas sem retornar nada pro shell atual. Mas se eles são tão similares assim, por que o $(()) aceita que eu referencie dentro dele os nomes de variáveis com ou sem $, enquanto o (()) aceita somente sem sifrão? Exemplo:

```
x=1
echo $((x)) # funciona
echo $(($x)) # funciona
((x++)) # funciona
(($x++)) # dá erro, pois coloquei o $ no nome da variável
```

Pode parecer uma pergunta desnecessária, mas gostaria de entender essa diferença de comportamento dos dois operadores, do primeiro aceitar eu chamar uma variável das duas maneiras (com e sem $) e do segundo não aceitar. Ou será que esses dois operadores não são tão similares como estou achando que são?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paulo,
isto não é uma resposta mas sim um comentário longo

De um modo simplicista:

```
$x       ---> val(x)
(( exp )) --> eval(exp)
```

Ou seja o teu exemplo em câmara lenta:

```
echo $((x))
:: echo val(eval(x)) ==> echo val(1) ==> echo 1 ==> 1

echo $(($x)) # funciona
:: echo $((1)) ==> echo val(eval(1)) ==> echo val(1) ==> 1

((x++)) # funciona
:: eval(x++) ==> ...alterou x para 2

(($x++)) # dá erro,
:: eval(val(x)++) ==> eval(1++) ==> erro(não posso incrementar "1")
```

Comment: Seu comentário me fez entender a diferença.

Comment: Obrigado. Ainda assim a notação é pouco clara...